# Why is the folder in ~/Library/Application\ Support called "Avian" for Textmate 2?

Tags: textmate

I would expect one of:

- ~/Library/Application\ Support/Textmate
- ~/Library/Application\ Support/Textmate2

Or maybe:

- ~/Library/Application\ Support/Macromates

What's the story here?

Comment: I have no folder called 'Avian' on my system. Why are you so sure it's related to Texmate?

Comment: @Thecafremo I have it too, and I'm sure it's related to TM.

Comment: @Thecafremo: instructions for installing bundles say to use that folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Avian" was the project's 'code' or 'working' name so the developers chose that string over the other choices.

Comment: Seems like a silly choice to me. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree - it's a really bad choice to name the folder "Avian". It looks like some developer hardcoded his name into the bundle's path for development and forgot to change it back.

Even if you read instructions about this in a blog post, you would assume that "Avian" is just the author's name.

For everyone who doesn't know this, it is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It also caused a bug with the theme files. My code folding icons vanished in the gutter. I removed textmate then re-installed. This fixed the issue until I closed textmate and opened it again. The fix was to remove this folder before installing textmate again.